# Remove the [.net] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

There is a newly created tag [.net](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net) with two closed questions using the tag. Since User Experience doesn't relate to specific frameworks, should we delete it or post a DO NOT USE in the Tag Wiki Excerpts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both questions were totally off topic and had no answers and no UX-relevant information, I just deleted the posts. The tag will disappear from the system soon as it's no longer on any questions.

Comment: Maybe we should do the same with the closed question having [tag:airplane] and [tag:aircraft]?

Comment: @BennySkogberg poof. Though note closed questions scoring -1 or lower with no answers are auto-deleted after a month

Comment: Cool, auto-cleanup on *.SO

Comment: I just did similarly to the [tag:backgound-images] tag (note the typo), but it didn't remove it from [the list](http://ux.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=name) for me (perhaps there's just a lag).

Comment: @KitGrose yeah, everything is cached for widely varying periods of time. Tag related stuff seems to take 5-10 minutes. It's fun when you mix up a tag synonym and do it twice and have no idea what the final result was for several minutes...

Comment: I'm still seeing it now (it's been there empty for 12+ hours). Worried I've missed a step!

Comment: @KitGrose do you mean the tag page or the list? Only the properly spelled version shows in the list for me. The /questions/tagged/ page always shows up even if the tag doesn't "exist", it just shows 0 questions

Comment: @BenBrocka it's now not showing in the list for me anymore. No worries!